# Custom Format Exception c# - exception is being unhandled, why?

Tags: c#, exception

I tried to use a custom exception for the below code.
When users enter a string instead of int number it should show a message from `AgeException`. but it shows an unhandled exception.

````
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Age: ");
                int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if(age>40 || age<6){
                     throw new AgeException(age);
                   }
                else{
                     Console.WriteLine("Your age is :"+age);
                   }
                
            }

            // when (ex.Message.Length>50)
            catch(AgeException ex) //when (ex.Message.Length>15)
            {
                //throw ex;
                Console.WriteLine("Errorrrrr from Age exception class: "+ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            //catch(Exception ex)
            //{
            //     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //    Console.WriteLine("\n\n"+ex.StackTrace);
                
            //}


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class AgeException : FormatException
    {
        private int messageDetails;
        // private string messageage;

        public AgeException() {        }
        public AgeException(int age) : base(String.Format("Invalid Student AGe: {0}", age))
        {
            messageDetails = age;
        }
        
       public override string Message => $"Invalid age: {messageDetails}";
        //public override string Message => $"Invalid age: {messageage}";

    }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmWay.png
````

Comment: Simple. your convert throws the exception not your condition.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` throws `FormatException`, it doesn't throw an `AgeException`. While it's true that `AgeException` is a `FormatException`, it doesn't mean that `FormatException` is an `AgeException`...

Comment: Try : if (!int.tryParse(console.readline(), out age)){throw new AgeException()}

Comment: @ZoharPeled then what should I do so that while the user enters a string as age then it should throw AgeException? How can I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't throw an exception in that case at all. That's why we have `int.TryParse`

Answer (score 0):

you can check if user enter number only

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Age: ");
    int age;
    
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
    {
         Console.Clear();
         Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number");
         Console.Write("Enter Your Age: ");
    }

    if(age>40 || age<6){
           throw new AgeException(age)
    }
    else{
        Console.WriteLine("Your age is :"+age);
    }
```